# Earth's Axial Precession and Frame Change

Tags: orbital-mechanics, earth, frames

Is Earth's Axial Precession and change in Axial tilt values significant enough to be considered while writing Rotation matrix that converts Body frame into ECEF frame and also while propagating Orbit in ECI frame?

Comment: Your question may be closed as a duplicate, but don't worry about it, it happens to all of us. If there's not enough information in answers to the other question, feel free to either modify this question to show why it's not satisfactorily answered there, or instead post a new question. I can suggest that "significant enough to be considered" is not very clear; one can argue "yes" and "no" equally well. Instead you might ask how fast errors will grow if you don't. Welcome to Stack Exchange!